# Which STL Container will be good to store millions of user define(class) data?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Suppose we've millions of custom data that need to be stored and search later these which STL will be good?
let's say

```
class A{ 
    public:
      int i;
      float f;
      string s;
};
```

We need to to store the objects of class A.

Comment: Use a database.  That's the purpose for them, storing large amounts of data.  Then use one of the C++ interfaces to the database that are available.

Comment: Maybe `std::vector`? But unless you tell us more, it's hard to tell much more.

Comment: What operations do you need? Appending? Inserting in a specific place? Deleting a specific item? Iterating over all items? What do you mean by searching, searching by what? Some form of key-value lookup?

Comment: [boost MultiIndex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)? Again depends what you want, a database may be the easiest option

Comment: More specifically suppose we are processing 100K integer data at a time and the requirement is that we need to find one of the elements from this data as predefine static data.
Let's say we need to find the presense of      int x=400

Answer (score 3):

> Which STL Container will be good to store millions of user define(class) data?

All of them, except for `std::array`.

> and search later

Depends on the kind of searching. The associative containers have efficient lookup operations.

Comment: agree but need to identify the best one. As I assumed that data is not dynamic so the list may not be a good option.

Comment: @user2417096 The first step in identifying the best data structure is to identify how you are going to use it. The requirement of "millions of data" isn't sufficient to narrow the choice down.